# Images into Qute Template

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

Does anyone know how to insert images into qute template?
I tried to write something in my HTML like:

```
<img src="../../../resources/templates/imgs/test.jpg" alt=""/>
```

but always got exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
```

and a lot of symbols of image code.

And the same question if image is SVG format.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't include images into the `templates` directory as otherwise they will get parsed by Qute as templates.

Just store the images in a directory outside of the `templates` directory. If you want them to be accessible as static resources, they should be in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`.

Note that you can also prevent Qute from parsing some files with `quarkus.qute.template-path-exclude` - https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#quarkus-qute_quarkus.qute.template-path-exclude .

**Note**:
If your are creating web application your relative path of the static assets should be same.
For example you are rendering an html file. You have some static assets in that html. Your html path is http://localhost:8080/your-app/v1/product/1. In this example the resource path is `your-app/v1/product`. So you should place static assets in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/v1/product`

But I don't think that's what you want as in any case, your images need to be accessible as static content.

Comment: An example showing the path in the `src` attribute would be helpful.

Comment: If you haven't defined a root path, files at the root of `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` will be at `/` so you could just use an absolute URL and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Works only variant with base64 : `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ........" alt=""/>`